# Interpreting the logarithm as a sum of simple poles along the negative real axis

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms, integral-transforms, divergent-integrals

I've heard it remarked that you can basically consider $\log z$ to be a function which has simple poles everywhere on the negative real axis (with a constant "residue density" at each pole).  This would be something like
$$ \log z = \int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{z + x} $$
But of course the integral on the right-hand side actually diverges.  We actually get
$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{z + x} = \lim_{b \to \infty} \int_0^b \frac{dx}{z + x} = \lim_{b \to \infty} \left( \log(z + b) - \log(z) \right) = \infty $$

In physics, there are a variety of methods for subtracting out the divergent part of such a limit to get a finite answer (various flavors of [regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_(physics)) and [renormalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renormalization)).  I'm wondering whether there is a standard approach here so that something similar can be done to "rescue" the first equation above from the divergent part of the integral.

Another way of phrasing the problem above is that I showed that the [Stieltjes transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_transformation) of a constant on the interval $(-\infty, 0]$ does not exist.  But perhaps there is another density function $\rho$ so that $\log z$ is the Stieltjes transform of $\rho$.
$$ \log z = \int_0^\infty \frac{\rho(x)}{z + x} dx $$
What is $\rho$?  Well, the Stieltjes inversion formula says that it should be given by
$$ \begin{align} \rho(x) &= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{\log(x+i\epsilon) - \log(x-i\epsilon)}{2\pi i} \\ &= \frac{(\log |x| + \pi i) - (\log |x| - \pi i)}{2\pi i} \\ &= 1 \end{align} $$

But this gets me exactly back to the integral that I started with, which is divergent!  Hopefully I am just missing something obvious.

**Edit: Alternate statement of question**

There has been a lot of confusion in the comments below about what I am looking for, so let me restate it in a very narrow way.  I would be satisfied with either of the following:

1. A sequence of meromorphic functions $f_n(z)$ with simple poles along the negative real axis with the following properties:

   a. The poles become dense in the limit $n \to \infty$.

   b. $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(z) = \log z$
2. A proof that there is no such sequence.

Comment: $\log z = \int_0^\infty (\frac{1}{z + x}-\frac1{1+x}) dx$ and those are not poles. This integral says that $\log z$ on $\Bbb{C}-(-\infty,0]$ is a limit of a sequence of meromorphic functions with poles on the negetive axis. Compare with the Cauchy integral formula.

Comment: Sure, I understand that they are not actual poles. It is the limit of a sequence of functions with denser and denser (but more lightly weighted) poles. But the question is where we can justify this interpretation in such a way that the integral makes sense. Your integral does not come with a justification.

Comment: I missed a minus sign. You meant the derivation of my integral, right?

Comment: No, I’m not asking for a proof of the equality. I’m asking what the *interpretation* is here. I can interpret my first equation as “Take the limit of $\lim_{\Delta \to 0} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\Delta}{z+ k\Delta}$.  Isn’t it neat that you get a logarithm?”  (Except that you don’t.)  This is an interpretation of a logarithm that is different than the standard one and sounds interesting. My question is an attempt to find such an interpretation that actually works.

Comment: Also, I am hoping that an answer will explain what I’m doing wrong with the Stieltjes transform and/or the inversion formula.

Comment: If you’re not convinced that this interpretation would be neat, let me give you an example of a neat observation that immediately falls out of it. “Why does the logarithm have a branch cut?” “Well, you can kind of define it that way, i.e., it is basically the sum of simple poles along the negative real axis.”  

From a conversation I had years ago, I was under the impression that this interpretation was (while not exactly well-known) something that has already appeared in the literature and/or been used as a pedagogical tool.

Comment: @reuns The problem is that I am not looking for a formula. I am looking for a formula with an interpretation. There are a lot of integrals that result in $\log z$, but I’m trying to figure out one that matches the interpretation in the title. If my comments above don’t make sense, then I will thank you for your effort and wait for someone who understands the question.

Comment: The problem with your 'continuous set of poles' idea is the Cauchy integral formula.

Comment: Why exactly is that a problem?  You can’t do a contour integral through the branch cut because the function isn’t defined there.

Answer (score 1):

The correct formula is
$$\log z = \lim_{T\to \infty} \log(z)-\log(1+\frac{z-1}{T+1})$$ $$=\lim_{T\to \infty} (\log(T+1)-\log(1))-(\log(T+z)-\log(z))$$ $$= \lim_{T\to \infty} \int_0^T (\frac1{1+x}-\frac{1}{z + x}) dx=\int_0^\infty (\frac1{1+x}-\frac{1}{z + x}) dx$$

There is no distribution such that $\log (x+iy) = \frac1{x+iy}\ast \rho$ because this distribution would have to be $C+1_{x>0}$ yielding a divergent integral.

Comment: Your last sentence sounds like you are trying to address the Stieltjes transform part of my question, but I don’t see the connection. Are you assuming that you can only use Stieltjes transforms on probability distributions?

Comment: Of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics) probability distributions are a small subset of those

Comment: I know what distributions are. I just don’t see why it is a problem to have a distributions which is 1 for all $x>0$.  That is a perfectly good distribution.

Comment: Yes but the convolution of $1_{x>0}$ with $1/(x+iy)$ doesn't converge.

Comment: Ok. So I’m pretty sure your last sentence is exactly equivalent to what I showed in the question.

Comment: So, my overall interpretation of this answer is as follows. We can rearrange this to $\frac{\log z}{z -1} = \int \frac{1}{(1+x)(z+x)} dx$. This shows that $\frac{\log z}{z -1}$ is the Stieltjes transform of $\frac{1}{1+x}$. This looks correct but doesn’t really answer my question.

Comment: Again I don't understand your comments. $\log z =\int_0^\infty (\frac1{1+x}-\frac{1}{z + x}) dx$ is the regularized  Stieltjes transform you asked for. What do you want more ? And the inverse transform assumes some regularity conditions.

Comment: Regularization requires an interpretation to show that you have not modified the original problem.  (There are many examples of this in physics, but I am not sure whether you would be familiar with any of them.)  One common approach is to set up another problem with an extra parameter (say, $\alpha$) that becomes equivalent to the original problem under a certain limit (say, $\alpha \to 0$).  The regularization succeeds if this limit produces a finite answer.  If you instead just take some arbitrary action to get rid of the infinity, then you have probably modified the original problem.

Comment: I think that I will just make the question extremely specific.  This is more specific than I would like to be, but I think it will help you understand.

Answer (score 0):

By fiddling around with my original suggestion above, I have one solution that meets my criteria:
$$ f_n(z) = - \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{n\frac{z}{1-z} + k} $$
This has poles at $z=-\frac{k}{n-k}$ for $0 \le k < n$ which becomes dense on the negative real axis as $n \to \infty$.

If we let $a=\frac{nz}{1-z}$, then
$$ f_n(z) = \psi(a) - \psi(a+n+1) $$
where $\psi$ is the digamma function.  As $n \to \infty$, $a \to \infty$, and the leading asymptotic behavior of $\psi(z)$ is $\log z$ as $z \to \infty$.  So we get
$$ f_n(z) \sim \log\left( \frac{a}{a+n+1} \right) \sim \log\left( \frac{1}{1 + \frac{1-z}{z} + 0} \right) = \log z $$

This works in a technical sense, but it seems more complex than it needs to be.  I would accept any answer which is more elegant, especially if it can be expressed in a Stieltjes-transform-like form.